# Pie chart in SSRS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report with 2 pie charts, giving sales data for product groups. Running a dataset from an OLAP cube.

I want to be able to select 2 different dates for each chart.
Example; Someone wants to compare November sales to the previous month. So one chart to display October, one to display November. Or they might want to see how Jan/Feb/Mar compare to Apr/May/Jun.

Can this be done from the same dataset, or do I need to point each chart to a separate dataset?

Answer (score 0):

If the dataset returns the data for both months, you could add filters to each chart to show the appropriate one. However, it sounds like you'd want this to be more dynamic.

I would suggest creating two separate datasets, each with a month parameter. This will allow the user to select any combination of two months. The charts would simply point to their respective dataset. You shouldn't incur a noticeable performance hit either way.

Comment: The issue I am having with this, is that when i create a second dataset (which is exactly the same as the first), when i add a parameter to the date field, because I already have one from the first dataset, a new date parameter is not created.

Comment: Oh, I see. In that case, add another parameter with the same settings manually. If there was a dataset populating values for the parameter, create another one with the same query (this would be a hidden dataset). In the dataset properties for the 2nd chart's dataset, go to the Parameter tab and switch it to the new parameter.